# Python Pandas: Filtering Rows Based on Multiple Lists Containing Multiple Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a large dataframe of about 5.5 million rows and 13 columns. I would like to filter the table based on the values of 2 columns: 'product_id' and 'return_reason'.

I would like to select the whole row if product_id and return_reason both have duplicated values.

For example, assuming I have the following df:

```
Index  product_id  return_reason  col3      col4      col5
1      A0001       Size_too_big   string31  string41  string51
2      A0001       Size_too_big   string32  string42  string52
3      A0001       Defective      string33  string43  string53
4      B0002       Defective      string34  string44  string54
5      B0002       Defective      string35  string45  string55
6      B0002       Changed_mind   string36  string46  string56
7      C0003       Size_small     string37  string47  string57
8      D0004       Size_small     string38  string48  string58
9      D0004       Size_too_big   string39  string49  string59
10     D0004       Size_small     string310 string410 string510
```

I would like to filter it such that I would get:

```
Index  product_id  return_reason  col3      col4      col5
1      A0001       Size_too_big   string31  string41  string51
2      A0001       Size_too_big   string32  string42  string52
4      B0002       Defective      string34  string44  string54
5      B0002       Defective      string35  string45  string55
8      D0004       Size_small     string38  string48  string58
10     D0004       Size_small     string310 string410 string510
```

I have tried using the groupby function:

```
dup_df = df.groupby(['product_id', 'return_reason']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
ismorethanNcount = dup_df['count'] > 1
dup_morethanN = dup_df[ismorethanNcount]
print(dup_morethanN)
```

This results in:

```
Index  product_id  return_reason  count
1      A0001       Size_too_big   2
4      B0002       Defective      2
8      D0004       Size_small     2
```

I then made the values of columns 'product_id' and 'return_reason" in the new DataFrame into lists:

```
list_productid = list(dup_morethanN['product_id'])
list_returnreason = list(dup_morethanN['return_reason'])
```

I then use the lists above as criteria to filter the df:

```
new_df = df[df['product_id'].isin(list_productid) & df['return_reason'].isin(list_returnreason)]
```

This gives:

```
Index  product_id  return_reason  col3      col4      col5
1      A0001       Size_too_big   string31  string41  string51
2      A0001       Size_too_big   string32  string42  string52
3      A0001       Defective      string33  string43  string53
4      B0002       Defective      string34  string44  string54
5      B0002       Defective      string35  string45  string55
8      D0004       Size_small     string38  string48  string58
9      D0004       Size_too_big   string39  string49  string59
10     D0004       Size_small     string310 string410 string510
```

As you can see, this method filters 'product_id' and 'return_reason' independently based on the list I give. What should I do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need rows with all duplicated by 2 columns use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['product_id', 'return_reason'], keep=False)]
print (df)
   Index product_id return_reason       col3       col4       col5
0      1      A0001  Size_too_big   string31   string41   string51
1      2      A0001  Size_too_big   string32   string42   string52
3      4      B0002     Defective   string34   string44   string54
4      5      B0002     Defective   string35   string45   string55
7      8      D0004    Size_small   string38   string48   string58
9     10      D0004    Size_small  string310  string410  string510
```

Or if need rows with 2 rows by 2 columns filter by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['product_id', 'return_reason'])['product_id'].transform('size').eq(2)]
print (df)
   Index product_id return_reason       col3       col4       col5
0      1      A0001  Size_too_big   string31   string41   string51
1      2      A0001  Size_too_big   string32   string42   string52
3      4      B0002     Defective   string34   string44   string54
4      5      B0002     Defective   string35   string45   string55
7      8      D0004    Size_small   string38   string48   string58
9     10      D0004    Size_small  string310  string410  string510
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I would like to only select rows if 'product_id' and 'return_reason' were duplicated 3 or more times? I do this by using pivot table on the 'product_id' of the 'DataFrame.duplicated'-filtered df and then filter them by 'count' column > 2. I then use the .isin method on the previously filtered df to get my results. Is there any more efficient method? Thank you!

Comment: @ilovedjians - then use `df = df[df.groupby(['product_id', 'return_reason'])['product_id'].transform('size').gt(2)]` - with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater like `2`

Comment: My hero :') Thank you so much!